# Split dependencies between packages with Pipenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package, pipenv

I am working on a Python codebase that is split between 3 different packages:

- `common` which is a library used by the other packages
- `datascience` which uses `common` and contains a lot of very large libs (numpy/scipy/...)
- `api` which only uses `common`

I am using `pipenv` to manage my dependencies and right now have a single `Pipfile` at the root, which contains all the libraries.
The problem is that `api` packages all the very large libs required by `datascience` even though it does not use them.

```
.
├── Pipfile
├── common
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── common.py
├── datascience
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── ds.py
├── api
    ├── __init__.py
    └── handler.py
```

I would like to be able to deploy the `api` package including the `common` package and its dependencies wihout the `datascience` package and its deps.
Similarly, I also need to build the `datascience` package including the `common` package and its dependencies wihout the `api` package and its deps.

I tried to do the following:

```
.
├── common
|   ├── Pipfile << Only contains deps used by common pkg
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── common.py
├── datascience
|   ├── Pipfile << Only contains deps used by datascience pkg
|   ├── __init__.py
|   └── ds.py
├── api
    ├── Pipfile << Only contains deps used by api pkg
    ├── __init__.py
    └── handler.py
```

`cd api && pipenv install -e ../common` but that failed.

Comment: I think there is something fundamentally wrong here. `pipenv` is for managing **application** dependencies. If you intend that your submodules can be run as independent applications e.g "python -m [submodule] - than it's OK. "I would like to be able to deploy the api package including the common package and its dependencies wihout the datascience package and its deps" - than you need to treat them as different packages and remove " single Pipfile at the root" or treat this "single Pipfile" as Pipfile for development environment